# How to retrieve value from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working on a project and I need some help regarding this:
I have a promise inside a function and I need to return the value of "current" so that I can use it elsewhere.
I'm retrieving data from Firebase, then I shuffle the result and extract only 10 elements from the result.

```
function retriveData() {

//declaration of variables ...

axios.get("Firebase link")
    .then((response) => {
        keyArray = Object.keys(response.data);
        let k = shuffle(keyArray); 
        //shuffle is a function to shuffle the key results
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            current[i] = response.data[k[i]];
        }
    });
return current;} //I want this variable to end up with the promise result in current
```

I know, this is not how promises work but I need a solution to solve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to make your retriveData function as a `Promise`

Comment: Whatever the solution is, the important thing is to return the value of "current" so that I can use it elsewhere in the code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.get` is asynchronous, so either you pass a callback to `retrieveData`, or it needs to return a `Promise` itself. There's no way around that.

**Using a callback (no error handling):**

```
function retriveData(callback) {
  axios.get("Firebase link")
    .then((response) => {
      keyArray = Object.keys(response.data);
      let k = shuffle(keyArray); 
      //shuffle is a function to shuffle the key results
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        current[i] = response.data[k[i]];
      }

      callback(null, current);
    });
}

retrieveData((err, result) => console.log(result));
```

**Using a Promise (no error handling):**

```
function retriveData() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    axios.get("Firebase link")
      .then((response) => {
        keyArray = Object.keys(response.data);
        let k = shuffle(keyArray); 
        //shuffle is a function to shuffle the key results
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
          current[i] = response.data[k[i]];
        }

        resolve(current);
    });
}

retrieveData().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

**[EDIT]** The above example is mean for illustrative purposes. Since `axios.get` already returns a `Promise`, it can be returned back directly from `retrieveData`.

```
function retriveData() {
  return axios.get("Firebase link")
    .then((response) => {
      keyArray = Object.keys(response.data);
      let k = shuffle(keyArray); 
      //shuffle is a function to shuffle the key results
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        current[i] = response.data[k[i]];
      }

      return current;
    });
}

retrieveData().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the promise returned by `Axios.get()` in your own promise, that's an anti-pattern. Just return the promise chain `Axios.get()` already gave you.

Comment: That's correct. I did it for illustrative purposes only, but forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I am making your retriveData function as a promise so you can use it anywhere in your program

```
function retriveData() {

//declaration of variables ...
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

axios.get("Firebase link")
    .then((response) => {
        keyArray = Object.keys(response.data);
        let k = shuffle(keyArray); 
        //shuffle is a function to shuffle the key results
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            current[i] = response.data[k[i]];
        }
       // if everything fine, if you get any conditional error then call reject();
       resolve(current);
    });
})
}


//call the function like promise
retriveData().then(result => {
//current will come here
     console.log('result comes here');
}).catch(error => {
    //error comes here (reject error)
   console.log('error');

})
```

Comment: My pleasure @HaithamHirt